# Adding an object to a PSQL table from my MainViewModel written in c#

Tags: c#, database, psql

I want to add a new user to my database with the following snippet.
"Kunde" is the object I am creating. "TempKunde" is its name.
It's supposed to call a procedure with the parameters that I have added, but doesn't do it.

Code is using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

```
Kunde TempKunde = new Kunde(Vorname, Nachname, Strasse, Hausnr, PLZ, Stadt, Geburtstag, WantsVK);

                    OracleCommand addCustomerCmd = new OracleCommand();
                    addCustomerCmd.CommandText = "p_create_kunde7";
                    addCustomerCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("vorname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TempKunde.Vorname;
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("nachname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TempKunde.Nachname;
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("strasse", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TempKunde.Straße;
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("hausnummer", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TempKunde.HausNr);
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("postleitzahl", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TempKunde.PLZ);
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("stadt", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TempKunde.Ort;
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("erstelldatum", OracleDbType.Date).Value = TempKunde.Erstelldatum;
                    addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("geburtstag", OracleDbType.Date).Value = TempKunde.Geburtsdatum;
                    //addCustomerCmd.Parameters.Add("kundenid", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    addCustomerCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that the output is commented out because it doesn't work. We tried doing it in our database directly, but not couldn't get it going as long as we had "kunden_id OUT INT" in our list of parameters. If anyone knows how we can get that to work, that'd be a different issue (and I'd thank you a lot) but our main issue is that we can't get the communication going.

The procedure is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE p_create_kunde7 (vorname IN VARCHAR, nachname IN VARCHAR, strasse IN VARCHAR, hausnummer IN INT,
postleitzahl IN INT, stadt IN VARCHAR, erstelldatum IN DATE, geburtstag IN DATE)
AS       
    id INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT max(kundenid) +1 INTO id FROM kunde;
    INSERT INTO kunde (kundenid, vorname, nachname, strasse, hausnummer, postleitzahl, stadt, geburtstag, erstelldatum)
    VALUES (id, vorname, nachname, strasse, hausnummer, postleitzahl, stadt, geburtstag, erstelldatum);
END;
/
```

If you need any additional information, please ask :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: We solved it. Had to pass the procedure in new OracleCommand();

Comment: I've rolled back your changes.  Don't edit your question to include the answer, scroll down and use the answer box to submit an answer.